# How folder sync(Sitecore Rock) feature is internally syncing assets?

Tags: sitecore-rocks

Once setup folder sync option for yours sitecore project, it automatically syncing assets(css,javascript).

How folder sync(Sitecore Rock) feature is internally syncing assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder Synchronization operates with two modes: `Copy and Mirror`.

In Mirror mode any change (update, create, rename or delete) is applied to the destination folder.

In Copy mode creates and updates are applied. Renames does not delete the old file and Deletes are not applied. This is a non-destructive mode.

In Mirror mode, this will execute a shell command like this:

```
robocopy <source> <target> /mir /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np
```

In Copy mode, this will execute the following shell command:

```
xcopy <source>\*.* <target> /e /d /i /y
```

**Source** https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/blob/master/docs/Tools/FolderSynchronization.md